# Is there a way to get all currently active apps in Android?

Tags: android

I need to lock other apps when they are opened by the user in some time period, but I don't want to implement a service that will check after every second that which app is opened and lock accordingly. I want that, somehow, Android will broadcast with active app information.

Is it possible, and if yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

Call `ActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses()`, It will give you the list of running apps.If you want to see the details then iterate through the `ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo` objects.

you can also check if your app is in Background or not by:

```
public static boolean isAppIsInBackground(Context context) {
    boolean isInBackground = true;
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningProcesses) {
            if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                for (String activeProcess : processInfo.pkgList) {
                    if (activeProcess.equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                        isInBackground = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
        ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
        if (componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
            isInBackground = false;
        }
    }

    return isInBackground;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want that, somehow, Android will broadcast with active app information.

That does not exist.